# Was Mohammad's Father a Christian?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, family

I have recently heard a claim that Mohammad's father was a Christian. The person I heard it from had reservations about the claim, thinking it false, so I hope that you can provide some facts and sources about Mohammad's father and what religion he was before Mohammad became the Prophet and if he converted after Mohammad became the Prophet.

Answer (score 2):

Prophet's father died before his birth.  Our prophet born as an orphan.  His father, however, was on the distorted form of Abrahamic faith.  He was not a Chrisitian. Of note, mostly people were idol-worshippers, but very few christians and jews were there during the birth of prophet Mohammad saws.

Comment: What do you mean "very few christians and jews were there"? There were definitely Christians and Jews during that time period and location.

Comment: @SystemDown It's quite plausible though. *Why?* Because Makkan pagans (majority, I suppose) were idol worshipers, used to bury their daughters alive etc. Christians and Jews on the other hand don't worship idol nor do they bury their daughters alive. Just saying. I maybe wrong.

Comment: @BleedingFingers - There are many confirmed Christians and Jews that have interacted with the Prophet. Most famous perhaps is Waraqa ibn Nawfal, a Christian scholar whom the Prophet first consulted when he first received Allah's message.

Answer (score 1):

Mohammad's (pbuh) parents were considered from Ahl al fatra that's mean they weren't Christian.
Many Islamic scholars put forward with clear evidence that Prophet Muhammads (pbuh) parents will be among the people of salvation in the afterlife, through similar explanations.

you can find full answer [here](http://www.questionsonislam.com/article/will-prophet-muhammad8217s-mother-and-father-enter-paradise-what-do-islamic-scholars-think-a).